# FFT library compilation on Windows

Tags: c++, fft

I'm using Visual C++ 6.0 on Windows XP and am trying to use FFTW or KISSFFT libraries for my project. Can someone help me understand how I can compile and link them to my program?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question would profit greatly if you would post a log of what you have done and tried, accompanied by the error that stopped you. People here are good and quick with answering specific questions, but don't want to take the time to write walkthroughs.

Comment: Why are there people still using the incredibly buggy Visual C++ 6.0? I would advise the OP to use at least VS2008 express edition instead.

Answer (score 1):

The authors of the library don't recomend to use Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler (http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html)

Read carefully documentation for FFTW library (*see ./doc/fftw3.pdf file inside FFTW library package*). According to 10.2 clause of documentation, there is no straightforward way to compile it under Microsoft Visual Studio, like open Visual Studio solution and press "build" button. But there is a hope you will be able to do that if you will follow recomendations in this clause.

> 10.2 Installation on non-Unix systems
>   It should be relatively straightforward to compile FFTW even on non-Unix systems lacking the
>   niceties of a configure script... bla bla bla

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are project files here : http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html . There is no reason to use VS 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://cygwin.org to build; i've tried before it work very well